# How do I get better resolution on my 30" monitor?

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

I have a Cyberpower PC running Windows 10 with an Intel HD Graphics 400 Adapter.  I just installed an HP LP3065 30" monitor connected via HDMI.  Here's the problem:  the max resolution shown on the Display Settings Resolution pull-down is 1280x768, which is unusable.  A previous post says that I should be able to get 1920×1200 through HDMI but I can't figure out how.  Can someone help me?

Comment: The monitor's native resolution is 2560 x 1600.  Anything else will not be as sharp.  The graphics card should recognize the monitor's resolution and it should be the default.  It will take some diagnostics to narrow down the cause of the problem.  BTW, a search on that monitor model number shows it as DVI rather than HDMI.

Comment: In the device manager under monitor does it say generic?  You need to install the INF from your monitors website if it does.  Also make sure you have the newest video card drivers installed.

Answer (score 1):

The multi display mode is probably set to Clone and this prevents you to set an appropriate resolution for the new monitor.

To choose a separate resolution for each monitor use this keyboard shortcut: Windows key + P key. In the panel on the right click on Extend.

Now you should be able to select a larger resolution for the 30-inch display.